# Calculus via a constructivist approach

Tags: secondary-education

A high-school teacher in the US whom I know, is
teaching [AP AB Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Calculus) for the first time.
He would like to use a [*constructivist* approach](https://web.archive.org/web/20171217164642/http://mathforum.org/mathed/constructivism.html):

> students explore mathematical problems and ideas and then, through whole-class discussions, students present their thinking and we as a class generalize the ideas and codify their findings.

He is seeking materials in line with this approach, to address the following
topics:

- Limits and their properties
- Differentiation
- Applications of Differentiation
- Integration
- Logarithmic, Exponential, and other Transcendental Functions
- Applications of Integration

I can make a suggestion for the functions item,<sup>*</sup>
but not so much the other topics.

---

<sup>*</sup>
"From Pop-Up Cards to Coffee-Cup Caustics: The Knight's Visor."
([arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1312).)

Comment: (1)  I suggest he teach it the normal way first.  Why do something in a non-standard fashion when you don't have knowledge of the standard?  This is hubris. (2) Whole class discussion is inefficient with large groups (normal class size) because few people are actively in the discussion.  (3)  You are going to lose the benefits of drill.

Comment: @guest: This teacher has experience using a constructivist approach in geometry and algebra (grades 8-11).

Comment: IMHO it would be a disservice to students to spend more than a single class  on such an eccentric approach. It is not even widely taught in universities.

Comment: As one example, the prolific cognitive scientist Daniel Willingham argues against this approach. I would recommend his book for K-12 teachers, "Why Don't Students Like School?". Ch. 6 has the following evidence-based thesis: **"Cognition early in training is fundamentally different from cognition late in training."** Implications for the classroom: "Students Are Ready to Comprehend but Not to Create Knowledge", "Don't Expect Novices to Learn by Doing What Experts Do", etc.

Comment: JOR:  That's good actually.  (If his kids kicked ass and outperformed other kids, even moving into a standard curriculum, that would really validate his approach).  All that said, he knows construction but not "teaching calculus".  Which was my point.

Comment: Also, I think student capability may make a difference.  If he is teaching braniacs at Thomas Jefferson high school, it will be a different situation than Texas A&M, which is different than business calc students at Flyover JuCo.  Some students will be better able to endure (or benefit from) non standard approaches.

Comment: Yikes!  Why is constructivism getting so much hate here?  You might disagree with the methods, but this is an established teaching philosophy.

Comment: The University of Michigan has been using a constructivist IBL ("inquiry-based learning") approach for its introductory calculus courses for nearly 20 years now with great success.  I think the skepticism expressed in the comments above is not well-founded.  Having said that, teaching in a constructivist manner requires exceptionally deep and flexible knowledge of the subject matter, and if this is the teacher's first time teaching Calculus then I am skeptical of how successful this will be.

Comment: I saw this pop up because someone did an edit, but looking at the comments, I wonder if people were getting confused between 1. [constructivism in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)) which denies the law of the excluded middle and leads to non-standard analysis and specialized calculus texts with infintesimals and 2. [constructivism in education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_education)) which involves constructing meaning and understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that he check out the POGIL approach to teaching.  They have a [Calculus](https://pogil.org/educators/become-a-pogil-practitioner/curricular-materials/materials-science-engineering-math-computer-science/calculus-i-a-guided-inquiry) book that he might find useful.

Comment: POGIL =  Process Oriented Guided Inquiry Learning.